# How to expand AppBarLayout when scrolling down reaches at top of the RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-coordinatorlayout, android-appbarlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I am working on one android app in which I am using `CoordinatorLayout`,`AppBarLayout` and `CollapsingToolbarLayout` to use the advance collapse bar functionality.

I am using recyclerview to show the number of items in the fragment. When I'm scrolling up recyclerview it smoothly collapse `AppBarLayout` but when I scroll down and reach at on the first item of the `recyclerview` it automatically stop scrolling without expanding `AppBarLayout'.

Then again I need to scroll down again to make `AppBarLayout` visible. So my requirement is that on scrolling down when I reach to top of recyclerview it must expand `AppBarLayout'.

How can we do this. Any idea ? Please see video of same https://www.dropbox.com/s/va5jk27ikytk5ax/app_collapsebar_issue.mp4?dl=0

Here is my layout of same :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/coordinator"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        >

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="220dp"
        android:background="@drawable/offer_image"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <!--    <com.flaviofaria.kenburnsview.KenBurnsView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="220dp"
            android:src="@drawable/offer_image" />-->
        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">


            <com.flaviofaria.kenburnsview.KenBurnsView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="220dp"

            android:src="@drawable/offer_image" />

            <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapse_frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#B3c85a00">

            </FrameLayout>

            <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/centerCircle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageViewCenter"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/offer" />
            </FrameLayout>

            <include
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            layout="@layout/toolbar" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="#FFFFFF"
            app:tabMode="scrollable" />
            <!--</FrameLayout>-->
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <!--<FrameLayout-->

        <!--android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
        <!--android:layout_height="match_parent"-->
        <!-- -->
        <!--android:visibility="visible">-->

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        style="@style/floating_action_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_share_white_24dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:backgroundTint="#FF9800"
        app:elevation="6dp"
        app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp" />

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left|bottom|fill_vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"></android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
        <!--</FrameLayout>-->

        <!--<include layout="@layout/content_scrolling" />-->

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/bannerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="58dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
        android:background="@drawable/curved_white_with_blue_border"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bannerText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:text="Banner"
        android:visibility="gone" />

        <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/bannerImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:visibility="gone" />

        <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/bannerClose"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/cross_icon" />
    </RelativeLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/socialTabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="46dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:background="@color/White"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/follow" />

        <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@color/White">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="46dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:weightSum="3">

            <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/facebookImageView"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/fb_follow" />

            <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/googlePlusImageView"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@drawable/google_follow" />

            <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/twitterImageView"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@drawable/twitter_follow" />
        </LinearLayout>
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    </FrameLayout>

    <ExpandableListView
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="265dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@null"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
    android:groupIndicator="@null"
    android:scrollbars="@null" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: please post some code.

Comment: @VipulAsri I have shared the layout of same

Comment: [check this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33597447/expand-appbarlayout-when-recyclerview-is-scrolled-fling-to-top)

Comment: @KushminderGarg how did you solve the issue ?

Answer (score 9):

I've just put together a [sample app](https://github.com/PPartisan/AutoExpandingAppBar) that seems to demonstrate the behaviour you're after. The `AppBar` will automatically expand whenever the `RecyclerView` beneath it is scrolled to the top, rather than stopping and waiting for another swipe to open the `AppBar`.

The most relevant components reside in a custom `RecyclerView` class. I've added a few explanatory comments:

```
public class ScrollFeedbackRecyclerView extends RecyclerView {

    private WeakReference<Callbacks> mCallbacks;

    public ScrollFeedbackRecyclerView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        attachCallbacks(context);
    }

    public ScrollFeedbackRecyclerView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        attachCallbacks(context);
    }

    /*If the first completely visible item in the RecyclerView is at
    index 0, then we're at the top of the list, so we want the AppBar to expand 
    **if the AppBar is also collapsed** (otherwise the AppBar will constantly 
    attempt to expand).
    */
    @Override
    public void onScrolled(int dx, int dy) {
        if(((LinearLayoutManager)getLayoutManager()).findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition() == 0) {
            Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "index 0 visible");
            if(mCallbacks.get().isAppBarCollapsed()) {
                mCallbacks.get().setExpanded(true);
            }
        }
        super.onScrolled(dx, dy);
    }

    /* the findFirstCompletelyVisibleItem() method is only available with 
    LinearLayoutManager and its subclasses, so test for it when setting the 
    LayoutManager
    */
    @Override
    public void setLayoutManager(LayoutManager layout) {
        if(!(layout instanceof LinearLayoutManager)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(layout.toString() + " must be of type LinearLayoutManager");
        }
        super.setLayoutManager(layout);
    }

    private void attachCallbacks(Context context) {

        try {
            mCallbacks = new WeakReference<>((Callbacks)context);
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(context.toString() + " must implement " +
                    "ScrollFeedbackRecyclerView.Callbacks");
        }

    }

    /* Necessary to interact with the AppBarLayout in the hosting Activity
    */
    interface Callbacks {

        boolean isAppBarCollapsed();
        void setExpanded(boolean expanded);

    }
}
```

`MainActivity.java`

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ScrollFeedbackRecyclerView.Callbacks{

    private AppBarLayout mAppBarLayout;
    private Toolbar mToolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ScrollFeedbackRecyclerView mRecyclerView = (ScrollFeedbackRecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rv_container);
        RecyclerViewAdapter mAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter();

        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        mAppBarLayout = (AppBarLayout) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
        mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

    }

    /* When collapsed, calling getY() on the AppBar will return a negative number. 
    Adding this number to getHeight() will return the same value as the toolbar's 
    height if the AppBar is fully collapsed.
    */
    @Override
    public boolean isAppBarCollapsed() {
        final int appBarVisibleHeight = (int) (mAppBarLayout.getY() + mAppBarLayout.getHeight());
        final int toolbarHeight = mToolbar.getHeight();
        return (appBarVisibleHeight == toolbarHeight);
    }

    @Override
    public void setExpanded(boolean expanded) {
        mAppBarLayout.setExpanded(expanded, true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, in method `isAppBarCollapsed()` variable `toolbarHeight` always contains value less value from `appBarVisibleHeight` - both values are never equal.

Comment: @IgorLevkivskiy Just tested out the repository in my answer and it stills seems to work. `isAppBarCollapsed()` returns true if the AppBar is fully collapsed.

Comment: It is strange behavior on different API. Did you try your code on different APi? If I run this code on 19 API - works fine, but if I run the same code on API 22 - it works wrong. I suppose problem could be in statusbar... But I'm not sure.

Comment: @IgorLevkivskiy I tested on emulators at API 16, 19 and 23 and they worked, though what you're saying about the status bar would make sense. (**Edit:** Just changed the emulator API 22 and that worked as well, so perhaps it's device specific)

Comment: Yeah my problem was in length of statusbar. Simply I add this height to `appBarVisibleHeight`. Simply I pass value of height to `isAppBarCollapsed()` Thanks

Comment: I obtained new problem. When I scroll up to AppBar RecyclerView stopped  below AppBar but not expand and when I continue scroll AppBar expanded - http://gifyu.com/images/ZAPISEKRANA10-30-20163-08-43PM.gif. What I want to do -http://gifyu.com/images/ZAPISEKRANA10-30-20162-41-42PM.gif  - When I long scroll up, AppBar automatically expand